# Forward or mount a /dev/ttyUSB file via ssh?

Tags: udev, ssh-tunneling

A USB device is connected to a server/machine (/dev/ttyUSB0) and I would like to access it as if the device file were located on my local machine. USB driver, udev etc.. on my local machine.

- Is there a way to forward or mount the file (as a SSH tunnel/port forwarding would work)? What would be the bare minimum to install on the remote machine?

It will help me a lot to debug the device remotely without having to tell users/clients to install something on their side.

Comment: see [usbip](https://www.kernel.org/doc/readme/tools-usb-usbip-README)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got success by following [this link](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_setup_and_use_USB/IP).

Just run below lines after installing the `usbIP`:

```
sudo modprobe usbip_core
sudo modprobe usbip_host
sudo modprobe vhci-hcd
```

Comment: trust you, set it as accepted, thanks